# When trying to run cli in docker for a container, im getting the "The /usr/bin/xterm does not exist please set the correct path".?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, containers, command-line-interface, kitematic

im using linux and trying to run a chainlink node on testnet with docker, after running docker-compose up I have two containers running in the docker, chainlink and postgresql DB. Im trying run a cli on the chainlink container, when I click on the docker cli icon in the bottom left corner im getting :

> The /usr/bin/xterm does not exist please set the correct path.

[image]

For terminal path in the setting I have: /usr/bin/xterm

For exec command shell in the setting I have the -sh option selected

Thx

<----------------------------------->

docker version 20.10.2

unbuntu  20.4

kitematic latest

Comment: It'd be kind of unusual for a Docker image to container `xterm`: it's not needed as part of most typical applications, and running X applications in Docker is tricky and platform-dependent.  Can you provide a [mcve] including your application's source code, its Dockerfile, and any details needed to run the container?

Comment: @heyvooo12 any luck on this?